# Check if array contains all elements of another array AND get the index in return

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a lot of Questions about if an array contains all elements of another array and they return only true or false but i need the index of where it starts,

Example:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
array2 = [7,8,9,10,11];
```

It should be index = 6

Edit:I have a static or constant array with the following numbers:  [2,5,10,5,5,5,8,1,4,6,2,7,6,3,8,2,4]
and i will get an array of numbers like this one: [2,8,3,8,4,2,3,2,2,4,2,8,2,6,***2,5,10,5,5,5,8,1,4,6,2,7,6,2,7,6,3,8,2,4***,2,3,7,3,12,3,8,2,2,6,3,2,3,2,9,2,5,2,3,5]
I need to find the sequence of numbers and the index of where it starts (in this case is 14).
I'm kind of new to programming that is why i'm asking for a simple solution with loops and if statements

I tried with something like this but it failed so bad

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_Input.length; i++) {
            if (array_Input[i] == 2 && array_Input[i+1] == 5 && array_Input[i+2] == 10 && array_Input[i+3] == 5 && array_Input[i+4] == 5 && array_Input[i+5] == 5) {var index=+ 1;} 
        }
```

**Note** that i haven't tried comparing one array with the other one

**Thank you all for your help**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? & What have you tried?

Comment: Pick your favourite [string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm). (You’ll have to implement it or find a library. Or hack in an [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) transformation into a string so you can use the built-in `indexOf`.)

Comment: This question is missing some detail.  Does the array simply need to contain all the elements of the other array, or does it need to contain them in the same sequence?  For instance, if the former is the requirement, I would expect `[11, 9, 7, 10, 8, 'watermelon', 'hat']` to be true with `0`.

Comment: English is not my native language and i'm a beginner in programming so i will try to explain: i tried with a "for loop" the size of my bigger array and with an "if (Bigarray[i] == 2 && Bigarray[i+1] == 3){ flag++} " but it never enters.

Comment: Yes they need to be in the same sequence, my Big array will allways change, but my second array is static, it will always be [2,5,10,5,5,5,8,1,4,6,2,7,6,3,8,2,4]

Answer (score 0):

you can check if array1 contains all values of array2 :

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
let array2 = [7,8,9,10,11];

let minOfArray2 = Math.min(...array2);

let flag = true;
let indexWhereItStarts;
let found = false;

array2.map( val => {
    if(!array1.includes(val)) flag = false;
});

array1.map( (val, index) => {
    if(val === minOfArray2) indexWhereItStarts = index;
});

console.log(flag);
console.log(indexWhereItStarts);
```

or you can check all with two one liner (reduce method) :

```js
    let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    let array2 = [7,8,9,10,11];

    let minOfArray2 = Math.min(...array2);

    let flag2 = array2.reduce((acc,val) => array1.includes(val) ? acc && true : false, true); 

    let indexWhereItStarts2 = array1.reduce((acc, val, i) => val === minOfArray2 ? i : acc, 0);

    console.log(flag2);
    console.log(indexWhereItStarts2);
```

Comment: This is checking and returning true false ask expected from the question but this does not return the index of where the match starts. *"but i need the index of where it starts*"

Answer (score 0):

You can check if slices of `array1` starting at various indices equal `array2` using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
function findIndex(a1, a2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length - a2.length + 1; i++) {
    if (a1.slice(i, i + a2.length).every((n, j) => n === a2[j])) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var array2 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
console.log(findIndex(array1, array2));
```

Comment: I think this is the only one so far that answers what the question is *probably* about, but it’s also O(mn) on the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: @Ry- Agreed, not the most efficient :)